# What should I do if I can't solve a physics homework problem and the deadline is coming up?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, education

To start off, please let me know if this question should be moved elsewhere.

Also, I think it's important that I should mention that I'm extremely frustrated by the way my undergraduate program is making me think. I don't like to rush from one concept to the other, barely studying it in depth and only memorizing a concept in the hopes (as claimed by my professors) that by understanding (by which they just mean memorizing) the concept, we will be able to apply it anywhere.

Anyways, my question deals with what to do with a homework problem that I just cannot solve. My UG program is loaded with what feels like a lot of writing work which takes time away from really thinking about physics. I really enjoy drawing situations in my mind as to how something might work, but with all the homework and other life priorities I just can't find the time to really wonder about some concepts in physics.

What should I do when I get stuck on a homework problem that I just can't figure out and time is running out to turn in the assignment?

Comment: This is not about physics. Maybe you can start be asking your friends to help.

Comment: Well....it is specifically about *physics* homework....

Comment: Things you can do:
- Ask other students what they did. Working together on problems is a very important thing to do when studying physics and is usually intended. Of course working together is different from copying someone's solution.
- Search for solutions of the problem online. This is also an important skill to have.
- Keep thinking about the problem.
- Accept failure as the time runs out. You shouldn't expect to be able to solve all problems you ever see.

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka I'm just really energetic and optimistic a lot of the time, and it usually gets the best of me. Also, I like to imagine that all of the best theorists (Einstein, Feynman, etc...) were able to solve all of the problems in their UG studies, so I want to be like them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about homework and not about physics.

Comment: @RobJeffries hence the *homework-and-excercises* tag...

Answer (score 1):

Well, try till the last minute. If you aren't able to do anything still, just write in whatever you've thought. The professor will then himself call you (in case you have had a good track record), or you can yourself approach him. You can then discuss with him what you were thinking (which even he will sense from your submission) and you can also share your problem about the excess writing rather than thinking you have to do.

Comment: Wow. What university did you go to where professors look at students homework assignments? I want that too. (Not ironic)

Comment: Yea some (if not all) of my professors seem to not really care about homework.